# Is Doctor Adams a self-insertion in Watership Down?

Tags: watership-down, richard-adams

In chapter 48, "Dea ex Machina", of *Watership Down*, we meet Doctor Adams.

*Watership Down* is of course written by Richard *Adams*.

**Is there any indication besides the surname that this character is a [self-insertion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-insertion) by Richard Adams?**

Or is the surname just a "coincidence"?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Doctor Adams is the author's father.**

Richard Adams is the son of Evelyn Adams, who worked as a country doctor.

I can find no definitive quote from the author to confirm this was his intention: however the similarity in name, profession and locale make it seem extremely likely.

Some critics have taken the similarity as read. For instance in his essay "[The Shrinking of the Epic Hero: Richard Adams' Watership Down and the Epic Tradition](http://www.academia.edu/19480011/_The_Shrinking_of_the_Epic_Hero_Richard_Adams_Watership_Down_and_the_Epic_Tradition_)", Kenneth Ketchell of Louisiana State University says in a footnote:

> The doctor is named Dr. Adams and, significantly, Richard Adams's father was a country doctor.

If university academics cannot source an explicit connection, it is possible that suppositions based on this strong circumstantial evidence is the best that we can do.

Comment: Add to this that the story started as a tale told to his own children.  Who wouldn't want to hear about grandpa in a story?